# Is there any standard procedure for drawing flight route in map?

Tags: html, google-maps, svg

I am creating a map using html and svg, I need to draw a flight route from one airport to another, I have seen that people are using curved lines to connect two airports, take a look at the below images, in that, curves differs from one image to another, is there any standard way to draw these curves (using lat and long or something else) or we can draw it just like that without any calculation?

Sample images:

[image: Image1]
<sub>(source: [virginamerica.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20130515185026/http://static.virginamerica.com/images/2013/misc/130220_routemap.png))</sub>

[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]
<sub>(source: [stayaspensnowmass.com](https://pt.stayaspensnowmass.com/sites/default/files/images/misc/eagle-flight-map.jpg))</sub>

Note: In my map, I am not plotting airports based on lat and long. It is plotted on some approximate point.

Comment: What do you _want_ to do?  You can easily make polylines [geodesic](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions), which will make them curve (the non-geodesic polylines appear straight on a mercator projcection). What do you mean by "not plotting airports based on lat and long"?

Comment: Is there any reason to vote down here?. can any one explain?

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort, and it is unclear.  Somewhat better with the pictures, but not all the issues in my comment have been addressed in the question.  The simplest answer is to draw geodesic polylines, all the pictures look to me like they were drawn that way only for visual separation.

Comment: My question is, is there any standard way to draw that curve for flight routes? In example images you can see each lines differs from one another, some lines are too curvy("Anchorage" to "San Francisco" line in first image) and some lines are like straight line("Los Angeles" to "Cancun"), why its like that? So, can i draw lines what ever convenient to me(Straight or curve line) or it is compulsory to  draw curved lines to show flight routes?

Comment: Found this looking for a how-to. Then I found a better how-to: http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/ -- possibly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

for Flightplans, you have to keep the Map projection in Mind.
there are different manners to "plot" the 3D-Earth to paper (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection).

to simplify: if you draw a straight line in your map, you have to fly a curved line, because the earth is spheric but plottet on your "2D-paper". otherwise you have to draw a curved line to fly straight in reality.

the pics your posted doesnt are flight plans, i dont see any logic in there, i think it just looks better for people when the lines are curved...